# Why is my summed range value not displaying the correct associated text?

Tags: javascript

I have 8 questions with radio buttons answers. Each answer has a value stored.

I've got a function to loop through all the forms and calculate the total value of all the selected answers.

I'm trying to display different text when the values are between certain ranges, but it won't work properly.

Any help appreciated.

```js
function DisplayPrice(price) {
  var val1 = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.form1.price1.length; i++) {
    if (document.form1.price[i].checked == true) {
      val1 = document.form1.price[i].value;
    }
  }

  var val2 = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.form2.price2.length; i++) {
    if (document.form2.price2[i].checked == true) {
      val2 = document.form2.price2[i].value;
    }
  }
  
   var sum =
    parseInt(val1) +
    parseInt(val2) +
  document.getElementById("totalSum").value = sum;
  
  $(function () {
    $("#submit").on("click", function () {
      if (sum <= 9) {
        $("#tolerance").replaceWith("<p>Conservative</p>");
      } else if ((sum >= 10) && (sum <= 15)) {
        $("#tolerance").replaceWith("<p>Moderately Conservative</p>");
      } else if ((sum >= 16) && (sum <= 28)) {
        $("#tolerance").replaceWith("<p>Moderate</p>");
      } else if ((sum >= 29) && (sum <= 39)) {
        $("#tolerance").replaceWith("<p>Moderately Assertive</p>");
      } else {
        $("#tolerance").replaceWith("<p>Assertive</p>");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
  <h3>Sample question 1</h3>
  <form name="form1" id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="5" name="price1" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="10" name="price1" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="15" name="price1" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">Answer 3
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="20" name="price1" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">Answer 4
    <br>
  </form>
  <br>
  <h3>Sample question 2</h3>
  <form name="form2" id="form2" runat="server">
    <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="4" name="price2" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">Answer 1
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="8" name="price2" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">Answer 2
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="12" name="price2" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">Answer 3
    <br>
    <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="16" name="price2" onclick="DisplayPrice(this.value);">Answer 4
    <br>
  </form>
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Calculate</button>

  <div id="tolerance"></div>
  
    <h3>Your score is:</h3>
  <input type="text" name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="" size="2" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: Your code is reporting a syntax error.

Comment: You shouldn't have a `+` at the end of the initialization of `var sum`. It should end with `;`.

Comment: Don't bind the `submit` event handler inside `DisplayPrice()`. Every time the user clicks on a radio button, it's going to add another event handler.

Comment: the sum Max value is 36, => `<p>Assertive</p>` (>39) will never happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so simple in pure JS:

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']
  ,   toleR  = document.getElementById('tolerance')
  ;
myForm.onsubmit=e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable form submit

  let sum = Number(myForm.price1.value) + Number(myForm.price2.value)
    , txt = '<p>Conservative</p>'
    ;
  if (sum >  9) txt = '<p> Moderately Conservative </p>'
  if (sum > 15) txt = '<p> Moderate </p>'
  if (sum > 28) txt = '<p> Moderately Assertive </p>'
  if (sum > 39) txt = '<p> Assertive </p>'

  myForm.totalSum.value = sum

  toleR.innerHTML = txt
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  }
p {
  display          : block;
  height           : 1.6em;
  background-color : lightgrey;
  padding          : .2em;
  }
h3 {
  margin-top: .7sem;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form" >
  <h3>Sample question 1</h3>
  <label> <input type="radio" value="5"  name="price1" required> Answer 1 </label><br>
  <label> <input type="radio" value="10" name="price1"> Answer 2 </label><br>
  <label> <input type="radio" value="15" name="price1"> Answer 3 </label><br>
  <label> <input type="radio" value="20" name="price1"> Answer 4 </label><br>

  <h3>Sample question 2</h3>
  <label> <input type="radio" value="4"  name="price2" required> Answer 1 </label><br>
  <label> <input type="radio" value="8"  name="price2"> Answer 2 </label><br>
  <label> <input type="radio" value="12" name="price2"> Answer 3 </label><br>
  <label> <input type="radio" value="16" name="price2"> Answer 4 </label><br>

  <br>
  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>

  <div id="tolerance"><p></p></div>

  <h3>Your score is:</h3>
  <input type="text" name="totalSum" value="" size="2" readonly >
</form>
```